# Using feature detection to check support for reserved words via dot notation

Tags: javascript, twitter, internet-explorer-8, browser-feature-detection

I am working on a site where we still need to support IE8, and we are trying to include the Twitter share button widget.

In IE8 we are seeing the 'Expected Identifier' error. This seems a common problem, and posts such as the following explain it fully and well:

- [Twitter widgets.js throws JavaScript error "Expected identifier" on IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205278/twitter-widgets-js-throws-javascript-error-expected-identifier-on-ie8)
- [Twitter button causing JS error in IE8 (Expected identifier)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178051/twitter-button-causing-js-error-in-ie8-expected-identifier)

Basically Twitter have stopped supporting IE8 (I wish I could do the same ;) ) - but more importantly, the error is caused by the fact that the Twitter widgets.js file appears to be referencing a property named `delete` via dot notation (that's what the first SO post I referenced above suggests anyway)

Based on the 2 above SO posts, there are 2 workarounds - either take a copy of widgets.js and change the property name from `delete` to something else; or use a conditional comment to prevent it being loaded in IE8

I don't like the idea of taking a copy (and having to maintain it forever!) of the widgets.js file, so I'm looking at preventing it being loaded in IE8.  But I don't want to use conditional comments; I want to use feature detection.

So I'm trying to write the following which I can use to decide whether to call the Twitter async library loading code or not:

```
NTJSLibrary.prototype.hostSupportsDeleteKeywordAsPropertyName = function hostSupportsDeleteKeywordAsPropertyName() {
    var testObj = {"delete":true};
    try {
        return testObj.delete;
    }
    catch (e) {
        // Host does not support referencing a property named 'delete' and has thrown an exception
        return false;
    }
};
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work because IE8 throws a `SCRIPT1010` error, which is a compilation/interpretation error, rather than a runtime error. IE doesn't throw an exception because it doesn't run!

Does anyone know how I can write a feature detection function to detect whether referencing the reserved word `delete` via dot notation will cause a compilation/interpretation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't just test it with a try-catch statement is that syntax errors are "early errors" in JavaScript, which means that the error is thrown immediately without even attempting to execute the code. (See 
[What types of errors are caught by try-catch statements in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526503/what-types-of-errors-are-caught-by-try-catch-statements-in-javascript) for a more detailed explanation.)

To work around this, we have to use some way to dynamically create code, which will avoid this issue. In JavaScript, you can do so using `new Function` or `eval` (in this case, using `eval` is acceptable as we are not executing user-defined code and there is no real way around using it).

An example of a test could be something like this:

```
function testReservedWords() {
  try {
    new Function('a.delete');
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```